Active Storage on cPanel generates empty blob links
i was developing a Rails application that worked fine on my local machine.
Since I deployed it on my shared hosting (by spaceship.com) with cPanel, I have some issues with Active Storage.
Note that the app is running on a subdirectory ("/my-app").
This is my code:

config/database.yml


local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>


config/application.rb


config.active_storage.service = :local
config.active_storage.routes_prefix = '/my-app'
config.active_storage.url_options = {
  host: 'https://mydomainname.com',
}



The files under the "storage" folder are present after the upload and I can see them correctly using the cPanel File Manager, but when I generate the url I get different situations: I get empty files or receive errors.
On the website, the generated link contains empty files and renders a blank page.

This is how the generated link looks like: https://.../my-app/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsiZGF0YSI6eyJrZXkiOiI1Y2N4Ymx0Y2p0eXo5endyYXI1c291dGh1M2ttIiwiZGlzcG9zaXRpb24iOiJpbmxpbmU7IGZpbGVuYW1lPVwiQXRsYW50aWNfbmVhcl9GYXJvZV9Jc2xhbmRzLmpwZ1wiOyBmaWxlbmFtZSo9VVRGLTgnJ0F0bGFudGljX25lYXJfRmFyb2VfSXNsYW5kcy5qcGciLCJjb250ZW50X3R5cGUiOiJpbWFnZS9qcGVnIiwic2VydmljZV9uYW1lIjoibG9jYWwifSwiZXhwIjoiMjAyNC0xMi0yMlQxMToxNToyMS43NjNaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--fd239fbf9b88f773ca1b27cd8cd88d7dbb9c4aa3/my-image.jpg

If I try obtaining the latest blob in the console with blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.last and then asking for its url with puts blob.url I get the following error:


ArgumentError, "Cannot generate URL for #{filename} using Disk service, please set ActiveStorage::Current.url_options."



I already tried to set ActiveStorage::Current.url_options both in the controller and in the config/initializers/active_storage.rb file but I get no differences.
Has anyone ever had the same issue?
Has anyone any idea on how to solve?

Yes, my bad. I asked my provider but they told me it’s my fault, and that they should allow it. Also, after some days the files are still there, but anyway they don’t work since the very first upload.

Rails already knows it's running in a subdirectory, there should be no reason to set config.active_storage.routes_prefix = '/my-app'. Did you try removing it?

Rails already knows it's running in a subdirectory > I've never set that manually, in fact I added the routes_prefix option because otherwise it would generate the routes based on the base domain name. Also, in the config/routes.rb file I had to use a scope with my "/my-app" to wrap all my routes inside the subdirectory. Is there any different way I should have configured the app to work on a subdirectory instead?

Soooo yourdomain.com/my-app leads to Rails root route? You can do that for sure, but this will cause you all kinds of problems. Why not run in a subdomain instead?

Exactly. I would prefer that too, but the issue here is about my hosting provider, which doesn’t allow me to use subdomains for my websites or apps. To reach what I did, I used a scope inside the routes.rb file and I added the asset_prefix option as well as the active storage prefix as shown up there. Anyway, even if the files are uploaded correctly, Rails seems not to be able to generate the url for them properly, and I can’t use those files inside the views.
